# Add a UIView with a UILabel to an existing view

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a Calendar inside a UIView that sits at the top of my UIViewController.  When the user takes certain actions I want to display a small message at the top of the Calendar by pushing the UIView down (around 50 pixels) and inserting another UIView with a UILabel inside.  This is the code I have so far. The existing UIView slides down after changing the constraint but the new UIView and UILabel are not visible.

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 50);
UILabel *labelInsert = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 100, 30)];
[labelInsert setText:@"Some Action Happened"];
[labelInsert setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
UIView *viewInsert = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[viewInsert setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
[viewInsert addSubview:labelInsert];
[self.view addSubview:viewInsert];
[self.constraintCalendarMenuViewTop setConstant:50];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that you have a navigation bar that hides the inserted UIView? 
Another possibility might be the constraint. Can you see the view if you comment the last line?

Comment: It was the navigation bar.  I didn't think of it.  Thanks.